# restful API using node not returning anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

In my **server.js** I do:-

```
app.post('/app/getSingleOrderDetail', function(req,res,next){
  orderController.getSingleOrderDetail(req.body.order_id);
})
```

then in models

```
exports.getSingleOrderDetail = function(order_id, res, res) {
   Orders.find({'_id':order_id}).exec(function(err,result){
     console.log('result: '+result) //it's ok!!
     res.json(result);
   });
};
```

I'm expecting the result with this `$http` call in angularjs

```
$http({
    url: '/app/getSingleOrderDetail',
    method: "POST",
    data: {'order_id' : id}
}).then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data)
    vm.sales_detail = response.data;
}).catch(function(response) {
    alert('Error!');
    console.log(response);
});
```

Everything is passed correctly but I just couldn't get the data back to client side in angularjs.

Comment: what are you getting in `req.body.order_id`? and are you getting value in `result`?

Comment: @abdulbarik it's fine, the id is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getSingleOrderDetail` you're expecting the arguments `(order_id, res, res)`, When you're invoking the function though, you're only passing in a value to the first argument, `order_id` and nothing for `res`. Also, you've defined `res` twice which is going to cause an issue in your code when trying to access `res`.

You should fix up those issues like so

#### Route

```
app.post('/app/getSingleOrderDetail', orderController.getSingleOrderDetail);
```

#### Model

```
exports.getSingleOrderDetail = function(req, res) {
  let order_id = req.body.order_id;

  Orders.find({'_id': order_id}).exec(function(err,result) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);

    console.log('result: ' + result); //it's ok!!
    return res.status(200).json(result);
  });
};
```

Just a side note, from the looks of your route name, this wouldn't be considered *RESTful*, it would be more of an *RPC* (Remote Procedure Call) style API.

Comment: @MariaJane I've cleaned up your code, and updated the answer with it

Comment: why you still need return json in the end? is res.status(200) needed here? what's wrong with res.json(result) ?

Comment: @MariaJane typically `return` is used in Node to ensure the code executions stop at that point, in the majority of situations this considered good practice. You wouldn't use return if you needed to do a clean up after return your response, like closing a DB Connection. `res.status(200)` is just explicitly setting the return `statusCode` to 200, you don't necessarily need it, `res.json(results)` would still return a 200. However, I find this syntax improves readability even though it is a bit more verbose.

Comment: So the code work still without return in front of `res.json(result)` right?

Comment: @MariaJane Yes, it would. However, if you remove the `return` from `res.status(500).send(err);` then you'll need to place an `else` before `res.json(result);`

Comment: do I still need to use return on res.json(result) if my erorr handling already had a return? coz if something happens it stopped there

Comment: @MariaJane No, you don't but, it is considered a good practice to use `return` if you have nothing to clean-up.